# not getting prompted for keypass while enerating a SSL certificate for tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, java-6

I am trying to enable SSL on tomcat and user the following command to generate my keystore

/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/keytool -genkey -alias grc -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore -storetype pkcs12

this works fine and a keystore is generated, however in all tutorials i find online, they state that as the last step i should be prompted for a keypass, which i then must enter the same values i entered for the first two prompts asking for the storepass. my problem : i never get this last prompt.

I am running this on Oracle Enterprise Linux 5.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keytool always uses the keystore password for the keys when using keystore type pkcs12.  It doesn't prompt for it because it can't be changed, and if you try to provide one with `-keypass` you'll get a warning stating it's being ignored.

Comment: _"It doesn't prompt for it because it can't be changed"_ In that case, why does [Tomcat official documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration) say so?: _"Finally, you will be prompted for the key password, which is the password specifically for this Certificate (as opposed to any other Certificates stored in the same keystore file)"_